# GeoTools example for Shapefile export to already existing PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, geotools, udig

I'm a newbie to GeoTool API, and I'm looking for a way to export the specific shapefile to the specific already existing PostGIS table with GeoTools (the underlying problem I face is that PostGIS tables are configured such as I can only view them with uDig but not other GIS; uDig can't edit them; I draw some additions on the separate layer, export then to the shape file and want to add them to the existing PostGIS tables whose data is used as a background when I draw the supplement in separate layer. Since uDig fails to export the shapefiles to the tables I desire, I have to do it manually, but I'd like to have some automation there)/

Comment: so do you want to fix UDig? or write a GeoTools based tool? since if UDig can't write to your DB it is unlikely the GeoTools can either (hint UDig is written using GeoTools)

Comment: i supposed that UDig's output to PostGIS is not tuned well; I'l like to have a simple command-line tool doin just one think - adding a shapefile geometries to specific PostGIS table.

Comment: shp2pg should do that for you then

Comment: Would be interesting to get more information about the problem to commit changes to PostGIS. Have you committed using the [commit-Button](http://udig.github.io/docs/user/reference/Edit%20Tools.html#commit) Have you added Features from a Database View? Could you provide a description of your workflow to find out what went wrong. IMHO I would use extra tools to push back the changes ;)